# Folders get recursive after being checked out on my local drive

Tags: c#, recursion, tfs, azure-devops

I keep having a situation where gets annoying (with TFS). I searched for "TFS" and "Recursive folder/files" but didn't find something similar in SOF and then good it but not exactly what I need.

I have checked out a project from TFS (#1) on my local machine and then after some modifications did update them on a new TFS (#2). Later noticed on TFS #2 have:

```
Solution folder
    folder 1/folder 2/files
    folder 2
    folder 3/folder 3/files
```

I checked back on TFS #1 things were OK however, for a reason when it gets to my local drive it can get recursive. Anybody knows what I have done wrong? or any settings are involved?

- One thing is that folders which go recursive are other developers projects.

Thank you!

Comment: Check your workspace mappings.

Comment: can you give more info? in there I see  my computer name which is the workspace name and computer name (same as worksapce), owner which is me and comment which is blank.

Comment: Make sure you are not trying to map the same local folder to multiple workspaces (TFS #1 workspace / TFS #2 workspace).

Comment: no I'm using 2 different folders (solutions) for each TFS so they are separated physically.

Comment: @Isaiah4110 I played with Workspace option under Source Control and resolved the issue after unmapping the solution folder, then moving the child folder to upper level and finally a check-out  Thank you

Comment: Sorry just saw your messages, glad that your issue is resolved.